# Ruby - get first X characters of a string that are numeric

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby

What would be a method that would create these results? I'm not very good at RegEx I'm afraid and couldn't see a relatively straightforward way to achieve this

```
"100124" => "100124"

"100asdf124" => "100"
"1asdf124" => "1"

"100 124" => "100"
"1 124" => "1"

"100.124" => "100"
"1.124" => "1"
```

**UPDATE**

This is NOT the same as extracting numbers from a string! Because I don't wnat to extract ALL numbers from a string, only the FIRST set until some other character or space or punctuation or whatever else that's not a number interrupts it! Added more examples to be clear

Comment: `"100asdf124"[/\d+/] #=> "100"`.

Comment: You also just call `to_i` on the string. It will return the first characters that can be xformed into integers

Comment: @Intl, `a1.to_i #=> 0`, which does nor descriminate between `'0a.to_i #=> 0`. Also, the OP wishes to return a string, not an integer. I assume `'a1'` is to return `'1'` or `nil` but that is not clear from the question.

Comment: What is the expected result if the string doesn't start with a digit or doesn't contain digits at all?

Answer (score 1):

Does this method solve your problem?

```rb
def numeric_prefix(string)
  match = string.match(/^\d+/)
  match[0] if match
end
```